# What type of Schema.org I have to use for bid annoucements

Tags: schema.org

I want to implement Schema.org for bid announcements and I'm a bit confused since there is no available type for it.

I have the following fields associated with it:

- title
- date of announced
- closing date and time
- body (announcement content)
- organization name
- organization address
- categories in which the announcement belongs

Comment: What is a bid announcement? Do you mean a [call for bids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_for_bids)?

Comment: yes since i want to tell to my clients all available rather can calling for a specific bid

Answer (score 0):

For [call for bids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_for_bids), you can use Schema.org’s [`Demand`](http://schema.org/Demand) type.

There is no property for the full text (if it’s not too complex/long, you could use the [`description`](http://schema.org/description) property) or for the categories.

You can use the [`seeks`](http://schema.org/seeks) property (with the `Organization` as domain) and/or the [`seller`](http://schema.org/seller) property (with the `Demand` as domain) to point to the `Organization` that has the demand.